# How to make an `if cond success failure` function in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am getting close with this:

```
myif() {
  if ([ $1 ]) then
    shift
    $*
    true
  else
    shift
    shift
    $*
    false
  fi
}
```

The main part is that `if ([ $1 ]) then` is not correct. I would like to be able to do these 3 things:

```
# boolean literals, probably passed in as the output to variables.
myif true successhandler failurehandler
myif false successhandler failurehandler
# a function to be evaluated
myif checkcondition successhandler failurehandler

checkcondition() {
  true
  # or:
  # false, to test
}
```

The following works to check a file:

```
file_exists() {
  if ([ -e $1 ]) then
    shift
    $*
    true
  else
    shift
    shift
    $*
    false
  fi
}
```

Wondering how to get the first example working where it handles those 3 cases. I've also tried using `eval` and doing this:

```
myif() {
  if ([ "$*" ]) then
    shift
    $*
    true
  else
    shift
    shift
    $*
    false
  fi
}
```

But no go.

Comment: You can use que expression `[ cond ] && success || failure`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to execute `$1`, and based on its success or failure, execute `$2` or `$3`. Here's one way to do it:

```
successhandler() {
  echo GREAT SUCCESS
}

failurehandler() {
  echo sad failure
}

checkcondition() {
  if (( RANDOM < 15000 ))
  then
    true
  else
    false
  fi
}

myif() {
  # disable filename generation (in case globs are present)
  set -f
  if $1 > /dev/null 2>&1
  then
    $2
    true
  else
    $3
    false
  fi
}
```

Here I've created arbitrary versions of successhandler, failurehandler, and checkcondition to demonstrate the behavior.

Here are some sample runs:

```
$ myif true successhandler failurehandler
GREAT SUCCESS
$ myif false successhandler failurehandler
sad failure
$ myif 'test -f /etc/hosts' successhandler failurehandler
GREAT SUCCESS
$ myif 'test -f /etc/hosts/not/there' successhandler failurehandler
sad failure
$ myif checkcondition successhandler failurehandler
GREAT SUCCESS
$ myif checkcondition successhandler failurehandler
sad failure
$ myif checkcondition successhandler failurehandler
GREAT SUCCESS
$ myif checkcondition successhandler failurehandler
sad failure
$ myif checkcondition successhandler failurehandler
sad failure
```

Inside `myif()`, I specifically drop stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`; adjust that as you prefer.